# Part of my ion-list view is not showing, and I can't scroll till I see these in Ionic3

Tags: ionic3

I have a shipping detail page with structure.

```
<ion-header></ion-header>
<ion-content>
   <ion-list>some ion-item's</ion-list>
   <ion-list>some ion-item's</ion-list>
   <ion-list>some more ion-item's (here my items aren't shown) and a button</ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer></ion-footer>
```

I can't see the last item and the button. scrolling is possible until I get to the last item in my list.

I can't seem to find my problem.
I have tried to extend my ion-content to get more space but this is isn't working for some reason.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Nick van Hurck

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this one with the use of ion-scroll.

```
<ion-content class="scrollable">
   <ion-scroll scrollY="true" class="scroll">
      <ion-list>some ion-item's</ion-list>
      <ion-list>some ion-item's</ion-list>
      <ion-list>some more ion-item's (here my items aren't shown) and a button</ion-list>
   </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
   .scrollable {
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }

   .scroll {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150%;
   }
```